# How to increase SQL performance for hash match left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlperformance

I found that the  query is taking a long time , due to hash Match  left join. The Hash Key probs  are

```
@tempHPDW.DeliveryWMID,@tempHPEng.EngID,Db.METRC.MetMeasure.MeasureId
```

I read that having index on these columns would be helpful. After adding the indexes should I sort.And change my table variable to temp tables.Also sorting based on these columns will it work.

Query:

```sql
SELECT distinct        
  NISD.EngID,        
  NISD.DeliveryWMID,        
  MEM.MeasureId,          
  1                  
FROM  #Master NISD          
inner join Db.metrc.MetMeasure MEM ON MEM.MetID = nisd.MetID     
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT ENG.EngID As EngID,          
     DMU.DeliveryWMID AS DeliveryWMID,          
     MEM.MeasureId AS MeasureID,          
     DMUT.DeliveryMoId  AS DeliveryWMUTypeID   


FROM @tempHPEng ENG          
INNER JOIN Db.DWMU.DeliveryWorkUnit DMUt ON DMUt.EngID = ENG.EngID          
INNER JOIN @tempHPDW DMU ON DMUT.DeliveryWorkUnitId = DMU.DeliveryWMID          
LEFT OUTER JOIN Db.METRC.DeliveryWMScope DS          
ON DS.DeliveryWorkUnitId = DMU.DeliveryWMID          
AND DS.EndPeriodDttm = (select MAX(EndPeriodDttm) from Db.METRC.DeliveryScope           
                 where DeliveryWorkUnitId = DS.DeliveryWorkUnitId           
                 AND MetID = DS.MetID          
                 AND EndPeriodDttm<=@LastReportingWeek)    
LEFT OUTER JOIN Db.METRC.MetMeasure MEM ON MEM.MetID = DS.MetID          
WHERE DS.InScopeInd = 'Y'   ) MIND ON MIND.DeliveryWMID = NISD.DeliveryWMID     
            AND MIND.EngID = NISD.EngID    
            AND MIND.MeasureID = MEM.MeasureId     
where nisd.DeliveryWMID <> -1 AND MIND.MeasureID IS NULL
```

Comment: Can you attach the execution plan? If switching your table variables to temp tables improves performance you may be interested in [trace flag 2453](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/table-variable-perf-fix)

Answer (score 0):

this might work
but your query does not make sense
you are joining on MIND.MeasureID  but then have a where MIND.MeasureID IS NULL

```
SELECT distinct NISD.EngID, NISD.DeliveryWMID, MEM.MeasureId, 1                  
  FROM #Master NISD          
  join Db.metrc.MetMeasure MEM 
    ON MEM.MetID = nisd.MetID  
   AND nisd.DeliveryWMID <> -1     
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       (  SELECT ENG.EngID As EngID,          
                 DMU.DeliveryWMID AS DeliveryWMID,          
                 MEM.MeasureId AS MeasureID,          
                 DMUT.DeliveryMoId  AS DeliveryWMUTypeID, 
                 rownumber() over (partition by DS.DeliveryWorkUnitId, DS.MetID order by EndPeriodDttm desc) as rowNum 
            FROM @tempHPEng ENG          
            JOIN Db.DWMU.DeliveryWorkUnit DMUt 
              ON DMUt.EngID = ENG.EngID          
            JOIN @tempHPDW DMU 
              ON DMUT.DeliveryWorkUnitId = DMU.DeliveryWMID          
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Db.METRC.DeliveryWMScope DS          
              ON DS.DeliveryWorkUnitId = DMU.DeliveryWMID
             AND EndPeriodDttm<=@LastReportingWeek              
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Db.METRC.MetMeasure MEM 
              ON MEM.MetID = DS.MetID          
           WHERE DS.InScopeInd = 'Y' ) MIND 
    ON MIND.DeliveryWMID = NISD.DeliveryWMID     
   AND MIND.EngID = NISD.EngID    
   AND MIND.MeasureID = MEM.MeasureId   
   AND rownum = 1    
 WHERE MIND.MeasureID IS NULL
```